# Sed to replace first occurrence after each pattern match

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have this line in my file:

```
select concat_ws('|',column1,'${hiveconf:RUNDATE}'), '${hiveconf:RUNDATE}' as date Group by concat_ws('|',column,'${hiveconf:RUNDATE}')
```

I need to replace `'${hiveconf:RUNDATE}'` with `string('${hiveconf:RUNDATE}')` but only when it is within `concat_ws`.

So I have 2 `concat_ws` in the same line, therefore if I give `g` in sed, it replaces all the `RUNDATE` and if I remove `g`, it replaces only the first occurrence.

After changing, my line should look like:

```
select concat_ws('|',column1,string('${hiveconf:RUNDATE}')), '${hiveconf:RUNDATE}' as date Group by concat_ws('|',column,string('${hiveconf:RUNDATE}'))
```

So the various patterns i have gathered till now are : `concat_ws('|',column1,coalesce(to_date(timestamp),"") concat_ws('|',columnA,to_date(a.timestamp),'01.01.00.01.01') concat_ws('|',column1,max(to_date(timestamp)),substr(id,1,9)) concat_ws('|',column,timestamp_d,'01.03.02',column2).`

Need to have the **timestamp** column cast as string.
The output file would look like:
`concat_ws('|',column1,coalesce(string(to_date(timestamp)),"") concat_ws('|',columnA,string(to_date(a.timestamp)),'01.01.00.01.01') concat_ws('|',column1,string(max(to_date(timestamp))),substr(id,1,9)) concat_ws('|',column,string(timestamp_d),'01.03.02',column2).`

Answer (score 2):

If your `concat_ws(...)` is never nested, that is if there is never something like `concat_ws(... foo() ...)`, so there is never a second set of parentheses within the `concat_ws()`, then you can match all occurrences of `concat_ws(`, followed by non-`(` until a `${hiveconf:RUNDATE}` and replace only those. Like this:

```
$ sed "s/\(concat_ws([^)]*\)\('\${hiveconf:RUNDATE}\)/\1string(\2/g" file
select concat_ws('|',column1,string('${hiveconf:RUNDATE}'), '${hiveconf:RUNDATE}' as date Group by concat_ws('|',column,string('${hiveconf:RUNDATE}')
```

Comment: Thank you, but cannot tell for sure that ```concat_ws(..)``` will not be nested. Wanted to see an approach where brackets are not considered because it is too dynamic.

Comment: @Jin I fear that would require a full-blown script where you keep track of how many `(` you've seen and how many `)` you've seen. I can't think of any other way of knowing if you are within the `concat_ws(..)` block :/

Comment: oh ok...thank you  for looking into this though.. because of the sheer size of files I need to make this change in and the different patterns which i am not able to generalize, I wanted to try this..to replace once after every pattern match, pattern being concat_ws....Will keep looking...Thank you :) @ terdon♦

Comment: @Jin what would the pattern be though? I mean, you can use something like `perl` which understands [regex lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html), but you have one case of `concat_ws('|',column1,'${hiveconf:RUNDATE}')` and another of `concat_ws('|',column,'${hiveconf:RUNDATE}')`. What can we rely on? What can we know won't change? Will `'${hiveconf:RUNDATE}'` always be immediately after the second comma of `concat_ws(`? We would need to see more of your file to come up wit any clever solutions.

Comment: i found the pattern to substitute if the column ( i.e. '${hiveconf:RUNDATE}') I need to cast as string is right next to ```concat_ws('|',```. But the problem occurred when the column was not right at the beginning.

Comment: So the various patterns i have gathered till now are : ```concat_ws('|',column1,coalesce(to_date(timestamp),"")```
```concat_ws('|',columnA,to_date(a.timestamp),'01.01.00.01.01')```
```concat_ws('|',column1,max(to_date(timestamp)),substr(id,1,9))``` 
```concat_ws('|',column,timestamp_d,'01.03.02',column2)```  Need to have the **timestamp** column cast as string.

Comment: @Jin please add all of this to your question so everyone can see it. This is completely different to what you have shown.